# Sending mail using DatabaseMail in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a profile called `GPMail`, and previously there was an account called  `comments@guitarplayer.com`, which was working as expected.

Now I want one more account with the same site, so instead of creating new profile I created new account called `password@guitarplayer.com` inside the same profile. But now when I try to send mail for password, I do not get the option for the account in the stored procedure -- `sp_send_dbmail`, so whenever I send the mail, the from field has the `comments@guitarplayer.com` address instead of `password@guitarplayer.com`.

Is there anyway that I  can specify the account name too with Profile name while sending mails?

Comment: @Abbas, I added more to my response below.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the method you use for sending mail: Yes

If you use sp_send_dbmail  (which is what I use), then yes, you can set the FROM address in the call to send mail.

See docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

@from_address  is what you want, I believe

If you want to actually log in to the mail server as a diff user, then you need to mod the profile or create a new one. The auth to the mail server is configured in the profile.